# RavenDB interface runs on Pipelight but can't authenticate in linux?

Tags: linux, ravendb

I have strange problem. Unfortunately i have to use RavenDB and  the local machine is linux. Thankfully i managed to install some silverlight support by using Pipelight and it seems to work ok.

Jut one thing doesn't work at all.

When i open the database interface, it loads in, shows my documents but when i need to authenticate and it opens the authentication window, it simply doesn't pass the authentication. Or as it seems to me, it even doesn't pass username and password further to the server at all.

(of course, i tested on windows from Internet Explorer and it works OK)

This is the error that i get:

```
Could not authenticate against the server

Message: [HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer]

Arguments: NotFound

Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.1.20513.0&File=System.Windows.dll&Key=HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer

Uri: /edit?id=asdf&database=test

Server Uri: http://asdfasfd/databases/asdfasdf/docs/asdfadf

-- Error Information --

System.Net.WebException: [HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer]

Arguments: NotFound

Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.1.20513.0&File=System.Windows.dll&Key=HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer

at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

at System.Func`2.Invoke(T arg)

at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise)

Inner StackTrace:

at Raven.Studio.Infrastructure.InvocationExtensions.Catch(Task parent, Action`1 action)

at Raven.Studio.Models.EditableDocumentModel.SaveDocumentCommand.SaveDocument()

at Raven.Studio.Models.EditableDocumentModel.SaveDocumentCommand.Execute(Object parameter)

at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.ExecuteCommand()

at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()

at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()

at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)

at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)

at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)
```

Comment: It is possible that Pipelight doesn't support Windows Auth. Try using API Keys, instead.

Comment: Thank you for reply. If i could user API that would be great :(